# How to draw a triangle the same size as opamp in circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I have an amplifier that I want to show as the same shape and size as an opamp but without the + and - signs, and without the two input ports... is there an easy way to do this? The `plain amp` element has the two input ports, and the `buffer` element is smaller.

Comment: Please, can you add your MWE or a figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the definitions for a shape I call `simple amp`. Include them into your preamble. Here is an example putting such a `simple amp` side by side with an `op amp`.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
%%% INCLUDE HERE THE CODE FROM BELOW DEFINING "simple amp"
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0) node[simple amp] {};
  \draw (3,0) node[op amp] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Definition of `simple amp`** (modified copy of the code for the `buffer` element)

```
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{simple amp}
    {
      \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
      \savedanchor\northwest{%
        \pgf@y= \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}
        \pgf@y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/plain amp/height}\pgf@y % <<<<< MODIFIED WRT. buffer
        \pgf@y=.5\pgf@y
        \pgf@x= \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}
        \pgf@x=-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/plain amp/width}\pgf@x % <<<<< MODIFIED WRT. buffer
        \pgf@x=.5\pgf@x
      }
      \anchor{south}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
      }
      \savedanchor\left{%
        \pgf@y=0pt
      }
      \anchor{in}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=0pt
      }
      \anchor{out}{
        \northwest
        \pgf@y=0pt
        \pgf@x=-\pgf@x    }
      \backgroundpath{          
            \pgfsetcolor{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/color}}   
            \northwest
            \pgf@circ@res@up = \pgf@y 
            \pgf@circ@res@down = -\pgf@y
            \pgf@circ@res@right = -\pgf@x
            \pgf@circ@res@left = \pgf@x
    \pgfscope
        \pgfsetlinewidth{2\pgflinewidth}
        \pgftransformxshift{.7\pgf@circ@res@left}
        \pgf@circ@res@step=\pgf@circ@res@right
        \advance\pgf@circ@res@step by -\pgf@circ@res@left
        \pgf@circ@res@step=.7\pgf@circ@res@step
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@step}{0pt}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
    \endpgfscope
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.7\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.7\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
      }
    }
\makeatother
```